# Visual Studio -- Expanded Intellisense View (Like a mapped treeview)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

When you are typing with Intellisense and it shows you the parameters within a class, you can select a parameter and keep going until you arrive at the base level.  When you are debugging, Visual Studio lets you stop on objects and inspect all of the parameters or fields within them.

Is there a way to build a treeview or diagram of all of the class parameters?  I have a large class that included ton of sub objects and properties and I would like to build a view of all of its properties.

Comment: Do you know about reflection?

Comment: I do not recognize that term.

Comment: Then you might want to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0cs7xez%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). E.g. there's a method called `GetMembers`.

Comment: Are you trying to see this in your IDE, or display it in your application?

Comment: It's just for my use. I am incorporating an existing data object into my program.  I need to know everything that is passed within that object.  I can certainly go though every parameter and check each one, but it would be a lot easier to view them all at once.  Ideally, I'd like to print a map of all the parameters so I can cross stuff off as I cross reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just talking about being able to visualize your classes (through Visual Studio, not actually building a hierarchy through code) you can do it like this:  In Visual Studio, click *View* - *Class View*.  This will give you a tree view of your classes.

If you click  *View* - *Object Browser* you will see a tree view of classes in other assemblies too, not just your classes.

**EDIT**

I think you are looking for something like the *Solution Navigator* in the [*Productivity Power Tools*](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) Visual Studio extension.  Click *Tools* - *Extension Manager* - *Online Gallery*.  Search for *Productivity Power Tools* and install it.  You will then see an option under the *View* menu for the *Solution Navigator*.

Comment: I can't expand past the class point.  I have an Application Class that incorporates an Applicant class that incorporates a ton of other smaller class.  I want to be able to view everything at once.

Comment: I essentially want the Solution Navigator idea to expand everything and let me print it. That's what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want control over the way variable values are displayed during Visual Studio debugging sessions, you can apply the [DebuggerDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) attribute to the class of interest.  You can alternatively overload ToString() on the class of interest to print the info you desire, assuming that this behavior would not conflict with any other requirements you may have.